# acmp 296 Лиса Алиса и кот Базилио - не проходит 3 тест, хотя ответ тот же

Tags: c++, математика, олимпиада

Не проходит 3 тест, хотя ответ тот же - 3 0
[image: Wrong answer на тесте 3]

[image: Вывод программы с ответом "3 0"]

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a,x,y,n; cin >> a;
    if(a%5==0) cout << a/5 <<  ' ' << '0';
    else if(a%3==0) cout << 0 <<  ' ' << a/3;
    else n=1;
    x=0;y=0;
    while(n!=0) {
        if(a%5!=0) {a-=5; x++;} 
        if(a%3==0) { cout << x << ' ' << y+a/3; break; }
        if(a%3!=0) { a-=3; y++;} 
        if(a%5==0) { cout << x+a/5 << ' ' << y; break; }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Не понимаю причину ошибки, помогите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот к чему все эти мучения? :)

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int N, d;
    std::cin >> N;
    d = 2*N/5;
    std::cout << 3*d-N << " " << 2*N-5*d;
}
```

Просто решите уравнение `5a+3b == N` на бумажке при условии, что `a+b` минимально...

**Update**

Вот, не поленился расписать математику... :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я просто недавно начал изучать с++

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать что означает d

Comment: См. обновленный ответ. Здесь не важен язык программирования, тут важнее математика.